# Were Gnostics/Gnosticism a recurring religion in Heinlein's work?

Tags: religion, robert-a-heinlein, starship-troopers

> Jelly glanced  over at Sergeant Migliaccio, first section leader. "Five
>   minutes for  the Padre," he stated. Some  of the  boys dropped out of ranks,
>   went over and knelt in front of Migliaccio, and not necessarily those of his
>   creed, either  -- **Moslems, Christians, Gnostics, Jews**, whoever wanted a word
>   with him before a drop, he was  there. (Starship Troopers)

I seem to vaguely recall hearing the word Gnostic/Gnosticism in a Heinlein context before, but cursory Googling didn't show any obvious hits.

Were Gnostics (or Gnosticism as a religion) a name used elsewhere in Heinlein's work?

Comment: Almost beat me to the first Heinlien question of the Heinlein week. +1 as a consolation prize (and for a great question :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not quite a direct naming of the religion, but *Stranger in a Strange Land* had a a character named "Professor" Simon Magus, a carnival grifter and mentalist who is described as a "likable scoundrel". [Simon Magus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_Magus) was one of the founders of Gnosticism.

The links between Gnosticism and *Stranger* run much deeper than a mere character name.

A very good article analyzing the links is an article "*[Whence Came the Stranger:
Tracking the Metapattern of Stranger in a Strange Land](http://pturing.firehead.org/occult/grok/thelema.htm)*". It's a little heavy on mysticism and such but a very thorough analysis.

Comment: This was also extensively discussed on `alt.fan.heinlein` - [here](http://omgili.com/newsgroups/alt/fan/heinlein/12fc740c-424b-4823-bc51-9fda4de2f3bfk1g2000prbgooglegroupscom.html) and [here](http://groups.google.com/group/alt.fan.heinlein/msg/853c6d159fe73046?&q=gnostic+agplusone&pli=1) are two good summaries

Answer (score 0):

"Job: A Comedy of Justice" is clearly a gnostic story where "God" is a spoiled and disruptive child (the Demiurge).